# Sum two columns line by line

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to create a column in my dataframe where I could sum two other column of the dataframe.

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 11:20)
```

Here for example, I want to add a third column z where I have :

```
z <- c(12, 14, 16,..., 30)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How have you tried to solve it?

Comment: This looks okay to me. If you don't like it, down vote it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arithmetic in R is [vectorized](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/vector/vector-arithmetics). That's a hugely important concept you should read up on. Columns in data frames are vectors, so your solution is simply:

```
df$z <- df$x + df$y
df$z
## [1] 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30
```

the same as if you just had `x` & `y` standalone vectors:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 11:20
x + y
## [1] 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30
```

Answer (score 7):

The function `rowSums` will do the trick:

```
df$z <- rowSums(df)
```

The result:

```
    x  y  z
1   1 11 12
2   2 12 14
3   3 13 16
4   4 14 18
5   5 15 20
6   6 16 22
7   7 17 24
8   8 18 26
9   9 19 28
10 10 20 30
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 11:20)
df$z<-c(df$x+df$y)
df

    x  y  z
1   1 11 12
2   2 12 14
3   3 13 16
4   4 14 18
5   5 15 20
6   6 16 22
7   7 17 24
8   8 18 26
9   9 19 28
10 10 20 30
```

Comment: Functionality of `with` comes handy here. `df$z <- with(df, x + y)`.

Answer (score 2):

Using data.table :

```
> library(data.table)
> setDT(df)[,z:=x+y,]
> df
     x  y  z
 1:  1 11 12
 2:  2 12 14
 3:  3 13 16
 4:  4 14 18
 5:  5 15 20
 6:  6 16 22
 7:  7 17 24
 8:  8 18 26
 9:  9 19 28
10: 10 20 30
```

Answer (score 1):

Using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(z = sum(x+y))
```

Other two options I've learnt in this answer to avoid grouping and writing the columns names [Sum across multiple columns with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28873057/sum-across-multiple-columns-with-dplyr)

```
df %>% mutate(z = Reduce(`+`, .))
df %>% mutate(z = rowSums(.))
```

Output:

```
Source: local data frame [10 x 3]
Groups: x

    x  y  z
1   1 11 12
2   2 12 14
3   3 13 16
4   4 14 18
5   5 15 20
6   6 16 22
7   7 17 24
8   8 18 26
9   9 19 28
10 10 20 30
```

Comment: Why do you need to group by `x`?

Comment: @Richard Scriven  If I don't group by x, `df %>% mutate(z = sum(x+y))`, the z column will be 210 in each row (the sum of df$x+df$y). I could use `df %>% mutate(z = rowSums(.))` or `df %>% mutate(z = Reduce(+, .))` to avoid grouping. I'll add them to my answer.