# Sum across multiple columns with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

My question involves summing up values across multiple columns of a data frame and creating a new column corresponding to this summation using `dplyr`. The data entries in the columns are binary(0,1). I am thinking of a row-wise analog of the `summarise_each` or `mutate_each` function of `dplyr`. Below is a minimal example of the data frame:

```
library(dplyr)
df=data.frame(
  x1=c(1,0,0,NA,0,1,1,NA,0,1),
  x2=c(1,1,NA,1,1,0,NA,NA,0,1),
  x3=c(0,1,0,1,1,0,NA,NA,0,1),
  x4=c(1,0,NA,1,0,0,NA,0,0,1),
  x5=c(1,1,NA,1,1,1,NA,1,0,1))

> df
   x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
1   1  1  0  1  1
2   0  1  1  0  1
3   0 NA  0 NA NA
4  NA  1  1  1  1
5   0  1  1  0  1
6   1  0  0  0  1
7   1 NA NA NA NA
8  NA NA NA  0  1
9   0  0  0  0  0
10  1  1  1  1  1
```

I could use something like:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(sumrow= x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5)
```

but this would involve writing out the names of each of the columns. I have like 50 columns.
In addition, the column names change at different iterations of the loop in which I want to implement this
operation so I would like to try avoid having to give any column names.

How can I do that most efficiently?
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why `dplyr`? Why not just a simple `df$sumrow <- rowSums(df, na.rm = TRUE)` from base R? Or ```df$sumrow <- Reduce(`+`, df)``` if you want to replicate the exact thing you did with `dplyr`.

Comment: You can do both with `dplyr` too as in ```df %>% mutate(sumrow = Reduce(`+`, .))``` or `df %>% mutate(sumrow = rowSums(.))`

Comment: Yes, the base R `rowSums` function works well. However, trying the suggestions in `dplyr`; `df %>% mutate(sumrow = rowSums(.))` and 
`df %>% mutate(sumrow = Reduce(`+`, .))` generate errors. I had just thought of fitting the operation within a dplyr chain alongside other preceding and subsequent operations in the chain.@DavidArenburg

Comment: Update to the latest `dplyr` version and it will work.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095526/summarise-over-all-columns

Comment: Suggestions by David Arenburg worked after updating package dplyr @DavidArenburg

Comment: @boern David Arenburgs comment was the best answer and most direct solution. Your answer would work but it involves an extra step of replacing NA values with zero which might not be suitable in some cases.

Comment: @amo I disagree: Davids first comment didn't utilize `dplyr` like requested plus requires the exact same step of removing `NA`s by `na.rm = TRUE`. His second comment is `dplyr` but (since the `NA` treatment is missing) it leads to `NA` sums.

Comment: @Boern So your are basically saying my comment is invalid because I didn't add `na.rm = TRUE` while your answer with an extra `replace` step and then using my exact comment is somewhat much better? Pretty sneaky (at best) statement and smells like rep wh*ring to me.

Comment: If you're summing across many rows in `dplyr`, your data is probably not "tidy" and it might be better to reshape or to just use base.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Honestly I'm having a hard time to recap, but if you look at the edit history my first post was just `summarise_each(funs(sum))`, a comment to my answer pointed out that this was the right answer, so I improved it. I don't remeber if I even read your comment. Either way, I don't think this discussion is worth our time :)

Comment: @DavidArenburg I want to select multiple columns (some numeric, some factors) all binary  (0,1) to summarize in rows as count and proportion. Is that possible using dplyr?

Answer (score 230, accepted):

#### dplyr >= 1.0.0 using across

sum up each row using `rowSums` ([`rowwise`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/rowwise.html) works for any aggreation, but is slower)

```
df %>%
   replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
   mutate(sum = rowSums(across(where(is.numeric))))
```

sum down each column

```
df %>%
   summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

#### dplyr < 1.0.0

sum up each row

```
df %>%
   replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
   mutate(sum = rowSums(.[1:5]))
```

sum down each column using [superseeded](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html?q=summarise%20_%20all) `summarise_all`:

```
df %>%
   replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
   summarise_all(funs(sum))
```

Comment: `summarise_each` sums down along each column while what is required is sum along each row

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same, but my DF has a column which is a character, hence I cannot sum all the columns. I guess I should modify the `(.[1:5])` part, but unfortunately I am not familiar with the syntax nor I don't know how to look for help on it. Tried with `mutate(sum = rowSums(is.numeric(.)))` but didn't work.

Comment: You could try to also replace all non numeric values with 0 using `replace(!is.numeric(.), 0) %>%` ?

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that I want to keep those non numeric values, so I'm afraid that if I did understand your suggestion properly it wouldn't be of much use.

Comment: I see. You might want to give `df %>% replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum))` a shot?

Comment: It also works with a character vector with the names of the columns you want to use, that can be a shortcut or not, depending the situation

Comment: Use `summarise_all` instead of `summarise_each` as it has been deprecated.

Comment: Syntax `mutate(sum = rowSums(.[,-1]))` may come in handy if you don't know how many columns you need to deal with.

Comment: Since this question and the answer really got popular - I think it worth update the answer using updated version of `dplyr` @Boern

Comment: Note that if you use rowwise/ rowSums on a grouped data frame with many many groups, it's worth to `ungroup` first - makes a huge difference in performance https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/5819

Comment: following a comment below, I would add `na.rm = T` to rowSums instead of converting the NA to 0.

Comment: `replace(is.na(.), 0)` I think is the same as `replace_na(0)`

Comment: @qwr No, `df %>% replace_na(0)` raises an error: *"Error in `replace_na()`: ! \`replace\` must be a list, not a number."*

Comment: @Boern your original code `df %>% summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(., is.na(.), 0)))` is a wrong use of `sum()`. I have revised it. You could check.

Comment: @DarrenTsai my bad. I use `replace_na` for individual columns.

Comment: Starting from dplyr 1.1, you should replace `fun(across(something))` with `fun(pick(something))`, see https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2023/02/dplyr-1-1-0-pick-reframe-arrange/

Answer (score 75):

### dplyr >= 1.0.0

In newer versions of `dplyr` you can use `rowwise()` along with `c_across` to perform row-wise aggregation for functions that do not have specific row-wise variants, but **if the row-wise variant exists it should be faster than using** `rowwise` (eg `rowSums`, `rowMeans`).

Since `rowwise()` is just a special form of grouping and changes the way verbs work you'll likely want to pipe it to `ungroup()` after doing your row-wise operation.

To select a **range by name**:

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(sumrange = sum(c_across(x1:x5), na.rm = T))
# %>% ungroup() # you'll likely want to ungroup after using rowwise()
```

To select **by type**:

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(sumnumeric = sum(c_across(where(is.numeric)), na.rm = T))
# %>% ungroup() # you'll likely want to ungroup after using rowwise()
```

To select **by column name**:

You can use any number of [tidy selection helpers](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/select_helpers.html) like `starts_with`, `ends_with`, `contains`, etc.

```
df %>%
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(sum_startswithx = sum(c_across(starts_with("x")), na.rm = T))
# %>% ungroup() # you'll likely want to ungroup after using rowwise()
```

To select **by column index**:

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(sumindex = sum(c_across(c(1:4, 5)), na.rm = T))
# %>% ungroup() # you'll likely want to ungroup after using rowwise()
```

---

`rowise()` will work for *any summary function*. However, in your specific case a row-wise variant exists (`rowSums`) so you can do the following (note the use of `pick` instead), which will be faster:

```
df %>%
  mutate(sumrow = rowSums(pick(x1:x5), na.rm = T))
```

---

#### Benchmarking

`rowwise` makes a pipe chain very readable and works fine for smaller data frames. However, it is inefficient.

**`rowwise` versus row-wise variant function**

For this example, the the row-wise variant `rowSums` is *much* faster:

```
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(1)
large_df <- slice_sample(df, n = 1E5, replace = T) # 100,000 obs

microbenchmark(
  large_df %>%
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(sumrange = sum(c_across(x1:x5), na.rm = T)),
  large_df %>%
    mutate(sumrow = rowSums(pick(x1:x5), na.rm = T)),
  times = 10L
)

Unit: milliseconds
         min           lq         mean       median           uq          max neval cld
 11108.459801 11464.276501 12144.871171 12295.362251 12690.913301 12918.106801    10   b
     6.533301     6.649901     7.633951     7.808201     8.296101     8.693101    10  a
```

**Large data frame without a row-wise variant function**

If there isn't a row-wise variant for your function and you have a large data frame, consider a long-format, which is more efficient than `rowwise`. Though there are probably faster non-tidyverse options, here is a tidyverse option (using `tidyr::pivot_longer`):

```
library(tidyr)

tidyr_pivot <- function(){
  large_df %>% 
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("x")) %>% 
    group_by(rn) %>% 
    summarize(std = sd(value, na.rm = T), .groups = "drop") %>% 
    bind_cols(large_df, .) %>% 
    select(-rn)
}

dplyr_rowwise <- function(){
  large_df %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(std = sd(c_across(starts_with("x")), na.rm = T)) %>% 
    ungroup()
}

microbenchmark(dplyr_rowwise(),
               tidyr_pivot(),
               times = 10L)

Unit: seconds
            expr       min       lq      mean   median        uq       max neval cld
 dplyr_rowwise() 12.845572 13.48340 14.182836 14.30476 15.155155 15.409750    10   b
   tidyr_pivot()  1.404393  1.56015  1.652546  1.62367  1.757428  1.981293    10  a
```

---

**c_across versus pick**

In the particular case of the `sum` function, `pick` and `c_across` give the same output for much of the code above:

```
sum_pick <- df %>%
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(sumrange = sum(pick(x1:x5), na.rm = T))

sum_c_across <- df %>%
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(sumrange = sum(c_across(x1:x5), na.rm = T))

all.equal(sum_pick, sum_c_across)
[1] TRUE
```

The row-wise output of `c_across` is a vector (hence the `c_`), while the row-wise output of `pick` is a 1-row `tibble` object:

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(c_across = list(c_across(x1:x5)),
         pick = list(pick(x1:x5)),
         .keep = "unused") %>% 
  ungroup() 

# A tibble: 10 × 2
   c_across  pick            
   <list>    <list>          
 1 <dbl [5]> <tibble [1 × 5]>
 2 <dbl [5]> <tibble [1 × 5]>
 3 <dbl [5]> <tibble [1 × 5]>
 4 <dbl [5]> <tibble [1 × 5]>
 5 <dbl [5]> <tibble [1 × 5]>
 6 <dbl [5]> <tibble [1 × 5]>
 7 <dbl [5]> <tibble [1 × 5]>
 8 <dbl [5]> <tibble [1 × 5]>
 9 <dbl [5]> <tibble [1 × 5]>
10 <dbl [5]> <tibble [1 × 5]>
```

The function you want to apply will necessitate, which verb you use. As shown above with `sum` you can use them nearly interchangeably. However, `mean` and many other common functions expect a (numeric) vector as its first argument:

```
class(df[1,])
"data.frame"

sum(df[1,]) # works with data.frame
[1] 4

mean(df[1,]) # does not work with data.frame
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(df[1, ]) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

```
class(unname(unlist(df[1,])))
"numeric"

sum(unname(unlist(df[1,]))) # works with numeric vector
[1] 4

mean(unname(unlist(df[1,]))) # works with numeric vector
[1] 0.8
```

Ignoring the row-wise variant that exists for mean (`rowMean`) then in this case `c_across` should be used:

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(avg = mean(c_across(x1:x5), na.rm = T)) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 10 x 6
      x1    x2    x3    x4    x5   avg
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1     0     1     1   0.8
 2     0     1     1     0     1   0.6
 3     0    NA     0    NA    NA   0  
 4    NA     1     1     1     1   1  
 5     0     1     1     0     1   0.6
 6     1     0     0     0     1   0.4
 7     1    NA    NA    NA    NA   1  
 8    NA    NA    NA     0     1   0.5
 9     0     0     0     0     0   0  
10     1     1     1     1     1   1  

# Does not work
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(avg = mean(pick(x1:x5), na.rm = T)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

`rowSums`, `rowMeans`, etc. can take a numeric data frame as the first argument, which is why they work with `pick`.

Comment: Note: before dplyr 1.1.0 `across` was commonly used as `pick` is here. However, `pick()` was created as a replacement for `across(.fns = NULL)`. `across` should only be used to apply a function(s) across multiple columns, not to return a tibble.

Answer (score 41):

If you want to sum certain columns only, I'd use something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df=data.frame(
  x1=c(1,0,0,NA,0,1,1,NA,0,1),
  x2=c(1,1,NA,1,1,0,NA,NA,0,1),
  x3=c(0,1,0,1,1,0,NA,NA,0,1),
  x4=c(1,0,NA,1,0,0,NA,0,0,1),
  x5=c(1,1,NA,1,1,1,NA,1,0,1))
df %>% select(x3:x5) %>% rowSums(na.rm=TRUE) -> df$x3x5.total
head(df)
```

This way you can use `dplyr::select`'s syntax.

Comment: I like this approach above others since it does not require coercing NAs to 0

Comment: And better than grep because easier to deal with things like x4:x11

Answer (score 34):

I would use regular expression matching to sum over variables with certain pattern names. For example:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(sum1 = rowSums(.[grep("x[3-5]", names(.))], na.rm = TRUE),
                    sum_all = rowSums(.[grep("x", names(.))], na.rm = TRUE))
```

This way you can create more than one variable as a sum of certain group of variables of your data frame.

Comment: great solution! I was looking for a specific dplyr function doing this in recent releases, but couln't find

Comment: This solution is great.  If there are columns you do not want to include you simply need to design the grep() statement to select columns matching a specific pattern.

Comment: @TrentonHoffman here is the bit deselect columns a specific pattern. just need the `-` sign: `rowSums(.[-grep("x[3-5]", names(.))], na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 33):

Using `reduce()` from `purrr` is slightly faster than `rowSums` and definately faster than `apply`, since you avoid iterating over all the rows and just take advantage of the vectorized operations:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
iris %>% mutate(Petal = reduce(select(., starts_with("Petal")), `+`))
```

See [this](https://albertotb.github.io/Benchmark-adding-together-multiple-columns-in-dplyr/#) for timings

Comment: I like this but how would you do it when you need `na.rm = TRUE`

Comment: @see24 I'm not sure I know what you mean. This sums vectors a + b + c, all of the same length. Since each vector may or may not have NA in different locations, you cannot ignore them. This would make the vectors unaligned. If you want to remove NA values you have to do it **afterwards** with, for instance, drop_na

Comment: I ended up doing `rowSums(select(., matches("myregex")) , na.rm = TRUE))` because that is what I needed in terms of ignoring NAs. So if the numbers are `sum(NA, 5)` the results is 5. But you said reduce is better than `rowSums` so I was wondering if there is a way to use it in this situation?

Comment: I see. If you want the sum and to ignore NA values definately the `rowSums` version is probably the best. The main disadvantage is that only `rowSums` and `rowMeans` are available (it is slighly slower than reduce, but not by much). If you need to perform another operation (not the sum) then the `reduce` version is probably the only option. Just avoid using `apply` in this case.

Answer (score 26):

I encounter this problem often, and the easiest way to do this is to use the `apply()` function within a `mutate` command.

```
library(tidyverse)
df=data.frame(
  x1=c(1,0,0,NA,0,1,1,NA,0,1),
  x2=c(1,1,NA,1,1,0,NA,NA,0,1),
  x3=c(0,1,0,1,1,0,NA,NA,0,1),
  x4=c(1,0,NA,1,0,0,NA,0,0,1),
  x5=c(1,1,NA,1,1,1,NA,1,0,1))

df %>%
  mutate(sum = select(., x1:x5) %>% apply(1, sum, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Here you could use whatever you want to select the columns using the standard `dplyr` tricks (e.g. `starts_with()` or `contains()`).  By doing all the work within a single `mutate` command, this action can occur anywhere within a `dplyr` stream of processing steps. Finally, by using the `apply()` function, you have the flexibility to use whatever summary you need, including your own purpose built summarization function.

Alternatively, if the idea of using a non-tidyverse function is unappealing, then you could gather up the columns, summarize them and finally join the result back to the original data frame.

```
df <- df %>% mutate( id = 1:n() )   # Need some ID column for this to work

df <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  gather('Key', 'value', starts_with('x')) %>%
  summarise( Key.Sum = sum(value) ) %>%
  left_join( df, . )
```

Here I used the `starts_with()` function to select the columns and calculated the sum and you can do whatever you want with `NA` values.  The downside to this approach is that while it is pretty flexible, it doesn't really fit into a `dplyr` stream of data cleaning steps.

Comment: Seems silly to use `apply` when this is what `rowSums` was designed for.

Comment: In this case `rowSums` works really well as does `rowMeans`, but I always felt a little weird wondering about "What if the thing I need to calculate isn't a sum or a mean?"  However, 99% of the time I have to do something like this, it is either a sum or a mean, so maybe the extra bit of flexibility in using the general `apply` function isn't warrented.

Answer (score 8):

### Benchmarking (almost) all options to sum across columns

As it's difficult to decide among all the interesting answers given by @skd, @LMc, and others, I benchmarked all alternatives which are reasonably long.

The difference to other examples is that I used a larger dataset (10.000 rows) and from a real world dataset (diamonds), so the findings might reflect more the variance of real world data.

The reproducible benchmarking code is:

```
set.seed(17)
dataset <- diamonds %>% sample_n(1e4)
cols <- c("depth", "table", "x", "y", "z")

sum.explicit <- function() {
  dataset %>%
    mutate(sum.cols = depth + table + x + y + z)
}

sum.rowSums <- function() {
  dataset %>%
    mutate(sum.cols = rowSums(across(cols)))
}

sum.reduce <- function() {
  dataset %>%
    mutate(sum.cols = purrr::reduce(select(., cols), `+`))
}

sum.nest <- function() {
  dataset %>%
  group_by(id = row_number()) %>%
  nest(data = cols) %>%
  mutate(sum.cols = map_dbl(data, sum))
}

# NOTE: across with rowwise doesn't work with all functions!
sum.across <- function() {
  dataset %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(sum.cols = sum(across(cols)))
}

sum.c_across <- function() {
  dataset %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(sum.cols = sum(c_across(cols)))
}

sum.apply <- function() {
  dataset %>%
    mutate(sum.cols = select(., cols) %>%
             apply(1, sum, na.rm = TRUE))
}

bench <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  sum.nest(),
  sum.across(),
  sum.c_across(),
  sum.apply(),
  sum.explicit(),
  sum.reduce(),
  sum.rowSums(),
  times = 10
)

bench %>% print(order = 'mean', signif = 3)
Unit: microseconds
           expr     min      lq    mean  median      uq     max neval
 sum.explicit()     796     839    1160     950    1040    3160    10
  sum.rowSums()    1430    1450    1770    1650    1800    2980    10
   sum.reduce()    1650    1700    2090    2000    2140    3300    10
    sum.apply()    9290    9400    9720    9620    9840   11000    10
 sum.c_across()  341000  348000  353000  356000  359000  360000    10
     sum.nest()  793000  827000  854000  843000  871000  945000    10
   sum.across() 4810000 4830000 4880000 4900000 4920000 4940000    10
```

Visualizing this (without the outlier `sum.across`) facilitates the comparison:

[image]

#### Conclusion (subjective!)

1. Despite great readability, `nest` and `rowwise`/`c_across` are not recommendable for larger datasets (> 100.000 rows or repeated actions)
2. The explicit sum wins because it leverages internally the best the vectorization of the sum function, which is also leveraged by the `rowSums` but with a little computational overhead
3. The `purrr::reduce` is relatively [new in the tidyverse](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functionals.html#reduce) (but well known in python), and as `Reduce` in base R very efficient, thus winning a place among the Top3. Because the explicit form is cumbersome to write, and there are not many vectorized methods other than `rowSums`/`rowMeans`, `colSums`/`colMeans`, I would recommend for all other functions (e.g. `sd`) to apply `purrr::reduce`.

Comment: This is consistent with my benchmarks as well. Great answer!

Comment: Thanks for adding this, but I was hoping you could clarify one thing. `reduce` works nicely since a lot of infix operators, particularly arithmetic operators, work element-wise due to the structure imposed by data frames (all columns must be the same length). So, `reduce` works great with `\`+\``, `\`-\``, `\`*\`` etc. However, you mention, *I would recommend for all other functions (e.g. sd) to apply purrr::reduce*. Can you elaborate on that? `reduce(df, sd)` would not work to get row-wise standard deviations, for example. As a matter of fact it won't get anything since it errors.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to sum across columns or rows using a vector but in this case modifying the df instead of add a new column to df.

**You can use the sweep function:**

```
library(dplyr)
df=data.frame(
  x1=c(1,0,0,NA,0,1,1,NA,0,1),
  x2=c(1,1,NA,1,1,0,NA,NA,0,1),
  x3=c(0,1,0,1,1,0,NA,NA,0,1),
  x4=c(1,0,NA,1,0,0,NA,0,0,1),
  x5=c(1,1,NA,1,1,1,NA,1,0,1))
> df
   x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
1   1  1  0  1  1
2   0  1  1  0  1
3   0 NA  0 NA NA
4  NA  1  1  1  1
5   0  1  1  0  1
6   1  0  0  0  1
7   1 NA NA NA NA
8  NA NA NA  0  1
9   0  0  0  0  0
10  1  1  1  1  1
```

Sum (vector + dataframe) in row-wise order:

```
vector = 1:5
sweep(df, MARGIN=2, vector, `+`)
   x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
1   2  3  3  5  6
2   1  3  4  4  6
3   1 NA  3 NA NA
4  NA  3  4  5  6
5   1  3  4  4  6
6   2  2  3  4  6
7   2 NA NA NA NA
8  NA NA NA  4  6
9   1  2  3  4  5
10  2  3  4  5  6
```

Sum (vector + dataframe) in column-wise order:

```
vector <- 1:10  
sweep(df, MARGIN=1, vector, `+`)
   x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
1   2  2  1  2  2
2   2  3  3  2  3
3   3 NA  3 NA NA
4  NA  5  5  5  5
5   5  6  6  5  6
6   7  6  6  6  7
7   8 NA NA NA NA
8  NA NA NA  8  9
9   9  9  9  9  9
10 11 11 11 11 11
```

This the same to say `vector+df`

- MARGIN = 1 is column-wise
- MARGIN = 2 is row-wise.

And Yes. You can use sweep with:

```
sweep(df, MARGIN=2, vector, `-`)
sweep(df, MARGIN=2, vector, `*`)
sweep(df, MARGIN=2, vector, `/`)
sweep(df, MARGIN=2, vector, `^`)
```

Another Way is using Reduce with column-wise:

```
vector = 1:5
.df <- list(df, vector)
Reduce('+', .df)
```

Answer (score 0):

If legibility is not a concern, but speed is, you can construct the desired `x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5` using rlang, then evaluate that.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(rlang)
df=data.frame(
  x1=c(1,0,0,NA,0,1,1,NA,0,1),
  x2=c(1,1,NA,1,1,0,NA,NA,0,1),
  x3=c(0,1,0,1,1,0,NA,NA,0,1),
  x4=c(1,0,NA,1,0,0,NA,0,0,1),
  x5=c(1,1,NA,1,1,1,NA,1,0,1))

# Construct a list of columns to sum, make them symbols
names_symbols <- syms(colnames(df))
# Construct an expression by placing `+` between each symbol
sum_expression <- reduce(names_symbols, ~expr(!!.x + !!.y))
# Evaluate that expression within the mutate
df <- df %>% mutate(sumrow = eval_tidy(!!sum_expression))

# Or, as a one-liner
df <- df %>% mutate(sumrow = eval_tidy(!!reduce(syms(colnames(.)), ~expr(!!.x + !!.y))))
```

A variant for the benchmark by @Agile Bean

```r
sum.implicit_explicit <- function(){
  dataset %>%
    mutate(sum.cols = eval_tidy(!!purrr::reduce(syms(cols), ~ expr(!!.x + !!.y))))
}
```

Performance: very little overhead over explicit, much faster than the normal reduce:

[image]