# Sum of two Columns of Data Frame with NA Values

Tags: r

I have a data frame with some NA values. I need the sum of two of the columns. If a value is NA, I need to treat it as zero.

```
a  b c d
1  2 3 4
5 NA 7 8
```

Column e should be the sum of b and c:

```
e
5
7
```

I have tried a lot of things, and done two dozen searches with no luck. It seems like a simple problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If NA are to be treated as 0, why not transform them to 0 and then do the operation?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
dat$e <- rowSums(dat[,c("b", "c")], na.rm=TRUE)
dat
#   a  b c d e
# 1 1  2 3 4 5
# 2 5 NA 7 8 7
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew there had to be a simple solution. I kept trying to apply the sum function by row, with no luck.

Comment: You can do this easily with `apply` too, though `rowSums` is vectorized. BTW, the best performance will be achieved by explicitly converting to matrix, such as `rowSums(as.matrix...`.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to expand this answer to a list of data frames. I tryed so far lapply(dat, function(x) x$e <- rowSums(x[,c("b", "c", "d")], na.rm=T)) and dat$e <- lapply(dat, function(x) rowSums(x[,c("b", "c", "d")], na.rm=T)) without success. Do you have an idea? Thanks

Answer (score 31):

`dplyr` solution, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33806717/5727278):

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(e = sum(b, c, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution, with concatenated `ifelse()`:

```
 dat$e <- ifelse(is.na(dat$b) & is.na(dat$c), dat$e <-0, ifelse(is.na(dat$b), dat$e <- 0 + dat$c, dat$b + dat$c))
 #  a  b c d e
 #1 1  2 3 4 5
 #2 5 NA 7 8 7
```

Edit, here is another solution that uses `with` as suggested by @kasterma in the comments, this is *much* more readable and straightforward:

```
 dat$e <- with(dat, ifelse(is.na(b) & is.na(c ), 0, ifelse(is.na(b), 0 + c, b + c)))
```

Comment: Perfect place where `with` will improve things: `dat$e <- with(dat, ifelse(is.na(b) & is.na(c ), 0, ifelse(is.na(b), 0 + c, b + c)))`.

Comment: I agree, much more readable! I edited the answer with your solution as well, if that's ok

Comment: totally fine @erasmortg

Comment: This neither efficient or robust. If you'd have ten columns you will have to nest 10 `ifelse` statements and who knows how many other statements too.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to keep NA if both columns has it you can use:

Data, sample:

```
dt <- data.table(x = sample(c(NA, 1, 2, 3), 100, replace = T), y = sample(c(NA, 1, 2, 3), 100, replace = T))
```

Solution:

```
dt[, z := ifelse(is.na(x) & is.na(y), NA_real_, rowSums(.SD, na.rm = T)), .SDcols = c("x", "y")]
```

(the data.table way)

Answer (score 3):

I hope that it may help you

Some cases you have a few columns that are **not numeric**. This approach will serve you both.
Note that: **c_across()** for dplyr version 1.0.0 and later

```
df <- data.frame(
  TEXT = c("text1", "text2"), a = c(1,5), b = c(2, NA), c = c(3,7), d = c(4,8))

df2 <- df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(e = sum(c_across(a:d), na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 2 x 6
# Rowwise: 
# TEXT        a     b     c     d     e
# <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 text1     1     2     3     4    10
# 2 text2     5    NA     7     8    20
```

Answer (score 1):

## dplyr

`rowwise` is [really inefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64595719/6382434) for even moderately sized data frames. If there is a row-wise variant that will be *much* faster. For summation this would be `rowSums`. You can use `pick` wrapped in `rowSums` to [tidy-select](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/language.html) columns you want to sum across:

```r
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(e = rowSums(pick(c:d), na.rm = T))
#   a  b c d  e
# 1 1  2 3 4  7
# 2 5 NA 7 8 15
```