# R: How to sum multiple columns of data frames in a list?

Tags: r, sum, lapply

i want to sum multiple columns of data frames in a list and only show the sum without showing the (calculation) input columns. Here an example:

```
ls <- list(data.frame(a=1, b=5, c=3, d=2), data.frame(a=NA, b=2, c=7, d=9))

ls
[[1]]
  a b c d
1 1 5 3 2

[[2]]
   a b c d
1 NA 2 7 9
```

my expected result is:

```
ls2
[[1]]
  c new
1 3   8

[[2]]
  c new
1 7  11
```

Any ideas how to do this? So far I tried to enhance this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31461357/sum-of-two-columns-of-data-frame-with-na-values) for lists, without success and without omiting the input columns (a,b,d). I tried so far lapply:

```
lapply(ls, function(x) x$e <- rowSums(x[,c("a", "b", "d")], na.rm=T)) 
and 
ls$e <- lapply(ls, function(x) rowSums(x[,c("a", "b", "d")], na.rm=T))
```

Thank you in advance

**Edit**:
Thanks Aech and Abdou for your answers, which work fine with this example. However, I have >200 columns, do you know a way without writing the columns that will remain? Like deleting the columns that I use for the calculation, instead of naming all columns.

EDIT 2:
Thanks for your improved code, it works well with the example data. However, with my true data set not... I get the following error:

```
Error in rowSums(x[, columns_to_sum], na.rm = T) : 
 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions"
```

My list has about 96 matrices with 200 columns and one row. But I don´t know how to prepare a reproducible example of my error. Any ideas?

Comment: Your other question is an exact dupe of this one. You can't post duplicate questions on SO. If this question is not good enough, then you should edit it, provide a minimal reproducible example and explain exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not name your list **ls**, because ls is a function.

```
lapply(myList, function(x) data.frame(c=x$c, new = rowSums(x[,c("a", "b", "d")], na.rm=T)))
```

Here is a solution where you specify the dropped columns only (after edit):

```
dropped <- c("a", "b", "d")
lapply(myList, function(x) {
  x$new <- rowSums(x[,dropped], na.rm=T)
  x[!names(x) %in% dropped]
  })
```

Comment: If we're being pedantic, you shouldn't name your vector `drop` because `drop` is a function. I agree that `ls` is a more common function and more likely to cause confusion, but all the same...

Comment: Instead of `x$new <- rowSums(x[,dropped], na.rm=T)` use `x$new <- ifelse(length((dropped)) > 1, rowSums(x[,dropped], na.rm=T), x[,dropped])`

Comment: Thanks.. see my new question on matrices: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39690633/r-how-to-sum-multiple-columns-of-matrices-in-a-list

Comment: However it is only used together with the data.frame `df` and does not occur alone (apart from that it obviously is the desired output). My suggested naming rule is admittedly more important when it comes to function definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
lapply(ls, function(x) {
    x$new <- rowSums(x[,c("a", "b", "d")], na.rm=T)
    return(x[,c("c","new")])
})
```

Edit:

You can put the columns you wish to use `rowSums` on into a variable as follows:

```
lapply(ls, function(x) {
    columns_to_sum <- c("a", "b", "d")
    x$new <- rowSums(x[,columns_to_sum], na.rm=T)
    return(x[,!colnames(x) %in% columns_to_sum])
})
```

Here `columns_to_sum` is the variable that saves the names of the columns you wish to apply `rowSums` on.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @N.Varela `columns_to_sum` cannot be one column. It has to contain more than one column, otherwise the `rowSums` function won't work.

Comment: I have >200 cols but only 1 row. Is this a problem for RowSums?

Comment: Thanks.. see my new question on matrices: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39690633/r-how-to-sum-multiple-columns-of-matrices-in-a-list