# R: How to sum multiple columns of matrices in a list?

Tags: r, sum, lapply

I want to sum multiple columns of matrices in a list and only show the sum without showing the (calculation) input columns (similar to my [former question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39420095/r-how-to-sum-multiple-columns-of-data-frames-in-a-list) on data frames). Thanks for the former answers, however I struggled to implement the ideas on matrices. Here an example:

```
ls <- list(matrix(c(1, 5, 3, 2), ncol=4), matrix(c(NA, 2, 7, 9), ncol=4))
countries <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
ls <- lapply(ls, "colnames<-", countries)
```

my expected result is:

```
[[1]]
     c new
[1,] 3   8

[[2]]
     c new
[1,] 7  11
```

Any ideas how to do this column summation? Thanks

Comment: Can you explain please your desired output? Why are you keeping `c` column? How is this different from the original question? What is your desired output for 200 columns?

Comment: c was only an example.. I have country columns which I want to add to regions. The only difference is that I asked before for data frames and now for matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

```
calc <- c("a", "b", "d")
keep <- "c"

lapply(ls, function(i){
  cbind(i[, keep, drop = FALSE],
        new = rowSums(i[, calc, drop = FALSE], na.rm = TRUE))
  })
```

Comment: works fine for the example. However, cbind(i[, "c"... (especially "c") is not suitable for my data as I have > 200 columns. Therefore I need a general solution without naming colums.

Comment: @N.Varela then you can keep "c" as variable as well outside lapply?

Comment: @N.Varela I think your example is not representative of what you are trying to achieve, please make your data more "real" and show the "real " calculation logic.

Comment: Thanks.. I tried: `keep <- COUNTRIES [! COUNTRIES %in% calc]` (COUNTRIES are all my colnames) which works fine