# How do I add a column to my data table that shows the sum of multiple other columns' values?

Tags: r

I have 8 age categories, with each of them having its own column (i.e. residents_under_5, residents_6_to_12, etc. Each column has a value between 0 and 3, for the number of people in that household in that specific age category. 
What I want is a new column with which I can plot the total distribution of age of my population on a histogram. So I was thinking of a column that has 66 rows of residents_under_5, 32 rows of residents_6_to_12, etc., for the sum of those categories.

My data looks like this:

```
a b c d 
0 3 2 1
1 3 2 1
2 0 2 1
3 1 0 0
```

What I want is a column e that shows:

```
e
a
a
a
a
b
b
b
b
b
c
c
c
d
d
d
```

For the total number of occurences in the other columns.

I've tried declaring new columns with `sum(residents_under_5)`, but that will give me 1 row with 66 (as the sum of that category). I can't plot a histogram with such a column. I hope someone can figure it out!

This is the dput() of the relevant columns

```
residents_under_5 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2), 
residents_6_to_12 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
        residents_13_to_18 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
residents_19_to_24 = c(0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
residents_25_to_34 = c(0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0), 
       residents_35_to_49 = c(0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2), 
residents_50_to_64 = c(0, 
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
residents_65_and_older = c(2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
        0)
```

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31461357/sum-of-two-columns-of-data-frame-with-na-values?

Comment: I just provided some data showing my issue

Comment: Can you provide a dput() of your base data set?

Comment: Provided it @RandallHelms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `unlist` the dataframe and calculate frequencies using `table` and then repeat `letters` using `rep`.

```
rep(letters[seq_len(ncol(df))], colSums(df))
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(residents_under_5 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2), 
                 residents_6_to_12 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                 residents_13_to_18 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                 residents_19_to_24 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                 residents_25_to_34 = c(0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0), 
                 residents_35_to_49 = c(0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2), 
                 residents_50_to_64 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                 residents_65_and_older = c(2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0))
```

Comment: Does this also work for data table? I have more columns than just these 4, how do I specify only the relevant columns? Do I just write 'names', or what should go instead? thanks!

Comment: @BenGill This is taking into consideration all the columns whether 4 or 100.You might need to subset the columns If you want to ignore them. For example, to ignore 1st column we might do `rep(names(df)[-1], table(unlist(df)[-1]))`

Comment: Apparently it doesn't work as I have negative values in my data set (error: invalid 'times' argument)

Comment: @BenGill I create a new dataframe using the `dput` of your relevant columns and updated the answer, Can you check now?

Comment: it gives me 5000 rows of "a"

Comment: @BenGill I tried re-reading your question and updated the answer. Make sure that `df` has only relevant columns. See if that works for you or else I'll delete the post since I am not able to help you.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked now. I first created a new data table with only the relevant columns. Your code gave me a vector with the right values. I declared it into a new variable as data frame, and will now plot it on a histogram!

Answer (score 1):

An option in `tidyverse` would be to get the `sum` of all columns with `summarise_all`, `gather` into 'long' format and `uncount` the 'value' column

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
   summarise_all(sum) %>%
   gather %>% 
   uncount(value)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(a = 0:3, b = c(3L, 3L, 0L, 1L), c = c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 0L), d = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
  -4L))
```