# R: join two dataframe columns into one

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with these columns:

```
   criticidad.x     criticidad.y
1            NA               60
2            NA               10
3            40               NA
4            40               NA
5            NA               NA
6            NA               10
```

How could I combine it so I get the following:

```
   criticidad.x     criticidad.y     criticidad
1            NA               60             60
2            NA               10             10
3            40               NA             40
4            40               NA             40
5            NA               NA             NA
6            NA               10             10
```

The dataframe has other columns that I'd like to keep untouched.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution might be:

First, ignore the NA values and do a simple row sum:

```
df$criticidad <- rowSums(df[,c("criticidad.x","criticidad.y")], na.rm = T)
```

Then correct for when both columns had NA values:

```
df$c[is.na(df$x) & is.na(df$y)] <- NA
```

There are more answers here: [Sum of two Columns of Data Frame with NA Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31461357/sum-of-two-columns-of-data-frame-with-na-values)