# create a new column which is the sum of specific columns (selected by their names) in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

My question is how to create a new column which is the sum of  some specific columns (selected by their names) in dplyr. 
For example, with iris dataset, I create a new columns called Petal, which is the sum of Petal.Length and Petal.Width.

```
iris %>% mutate(Petal = Petal.Length+Petal.Width)
```

Now imagine I have a dataset with 20 columns with 'Petal' in their names. I want to create a column 'Petal' which sum up all those columns. I definitely do not want to type all the columns names in my code.  Feel like there should be achievable with one line of code in dplyr. 
  Appreciate if anyone can help.

Comment: Sounds like your data are not in a tidy format. Better to `gather()` to long format and `summarize()`. There are many existing questions out there on "reshaping wide to long".

Answer (score 25):

I agree with MrFlick that tidying your data is preferable---especially if you want to do *anything* other than sum these columns---but here is one option:

```
iris %>% mutate(
   Petal = rowSums(select(., starts_with("Petal")))
)

    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species Petal
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa   1.6
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa   1.6
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa   1.5
4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa   1.7
5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa   1.6
...
```

See `?select` helper options other than `starts_with()` for selecting columns.

Answer (score 5):

Using `reduce()` from `purrr` is slightly faster than `rowSums` and definately faster than `apply`, since you avoid iterating over all the rows and just take advantage of the vectorized operations:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
iris %>% mutate(Petal = reduce(select(., starts_with("Petal")), `+`))
```

See [this](https://albertotb.github.io/Benchmark-adding-together-multiple-columns-in-dplyr/#) for timings

Answer (score 2):

```
iris %>% mutate(Petal = rowSums(.[grep("Petal", names(.))], na.rm = T))
```

This should work.

`names(.)` selects the names from your dataframe, `grep` searches through these to find ones that match a regex ("Petal"), and `rowSums` adds the value of each column, assigning them to your new variable `Petal`. The ".[]" syntax is a work-around for the way that dplyr passes column names.

Answer (score 2):

I gave a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64595719/6382434) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69776059/6382434). `rowSums` is the best option if your aggregating function is sum:

```
iris %>% 
  mutate(Petal = rowSums(pick(starts_with("Petal"))))
```

But you can use `c_across` and `rowwise`:

```
iris %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Petal = sum(c_across(starts_with("Petal")))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

The big advantage is that you can use other functions besides `sum`. `rowSums` is a better option because it's faster, but if you want to apply another function other than `sum` this is a good option.

You can use any of the [tidyselect](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html) options within `c_across` and `pick` to select columns by their name, position, class, a range of consecutive columns, etc.

**Output**

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Petal
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>   <dbl>
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa    1.6
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa    1.6
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa    1.5
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa    1.7
 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa    1.6
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa    2.1
 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa    1.7
 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa    1.7
 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa    1.6
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa    1.6
# ... with 140 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

More generally, create a key for each observation (e.g., the row number using `mutate` below), move the columns of interest into two columns, one holds the column name, the other holds the value (using `melt` below), `group_by` observation, and do whatever calculations you want. Below, I add a column using `mutate` that sums all columns containing the word 'Petal' and finally drop whatever variables I don't want (using `select`).

```
require(dplyr)
require(reshape2)

iris %>%
  mutate(observation = 1:nrow(iris)) %>% 
  melt(
    measure.vars = grep("Petal", colnames(iris)), 
    variable.name = 'variable', 
    value.name = 'value') %>% 
  group_by(observation) %>%
  mutate(Petal = sum(value)) %>% 
  select(-observation, -variable, -value)
```

While the above can be shortened, I thought this version would provide some guidance.