# dplyr rowwise sum and other functions like max

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, rowwise

If I wanted to sum over some variables in a data-frame using `dplyr`, I could do:

```
> head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa

> select(iris, starts_with('Petal')) %>% rowSums()
  [1] 1.6 1.6 1.5 1.7 1.6 2.1 1.7 1.7 1.6 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.5 1.2 1.4 1.9 1.7 1.7 2.0 1.8 1.9 1.9 1.2 2.2 2.1 1.8 2.0 1.7 1.6 1.8 1.8 1.9 1.6 1.6 1.7 1.4
 [37] 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.7 1.6 1.6 1.5 2.2 2.3 1.7 1.8 1.6 1.7 1.6 6.1 6.0 6.4 5.3 6.1 5.8 6.3 4.3 5.9 5.3 4.5 5.7 5.0 6.1 4.9 5.8 6.0 5.1 6.0 5.0 6.6 5.3
 [73] 6.4 5.9 5.6 5.8 6.2 6.7 6.0 4.5 4.9 4.7 5.1 6.7 6.0 6.1 6.2 5.7 5.4 5.3 5.6 6.0 5.2 4.3 5.5 5.4 5.5 5.6 4.1 5.4 8.5 7.0 8.0 7.4 8.0 8.7 6.2 8.1
[109] 7.6 8.6 7.1 7.2 7.6 7.0 7.5 7.6 7.3 8.9 9.2 6.5 8.0 6.9 8.7 6.7 7.8 7.8 6.6 6.7 7.7 7.4 8.0 8.4 7.8 6.6 7.0 8.4 8.0 7.3 6.6 7.5 8.0 7.4 7.0 8.2
[145] 8.2 7.5 6.9 7.2 7.7 6.9
```

That's fine, but I would have thought `rowwise` accomplishes the same thing, but it doesn't,

```
> select(iris, starts_with('Petal')) %>% rowwise() %>% sum()
[1] 743.6
```

What I particularly want to do is select a set of columns, and create a new variable each value of which is the maximum value of each row of the selected columns. For example, if I selected the "Petal" columns, by maximum values would be 1.4, 1.4, 1.3 and so on.

I could do it like this:

```
> select(iris, starts_with('Petal')) %>% apply(1, max)
```

and that's fine. But I'm just curious as to why the `rowwise` approach doesn't work. I realize I am using `rowwise` incorrectly, I'm just not sure why it is wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In short: you are expecting the "sum" function to be aware of `dplyr` data structures like a data frame grouped by row. `sum` is not aware of it so it just takes the sum of the whole `data.frame`.

Here is a brief explanation. This:

```
select(iris, starts_with('Petal')) %>% rowwise() %>% sum()
```

Can be rewritten without using the pipe operator as the following:

```
data <- select(iris, starts_with('Petal'))
data <- rowwise(data)
sum(data)
```

As you can see you were constructing something called a `tibble`. Then the `rowwise` call adds additional information on this object and specifies that it should be grouped row-wise.

However only the functions aware of this grouping like `summarize` and `mutate` can work like intended. Base R functions like `sum` are not aware of these objects and treat them as any standard `data.frame`s. And the standard approach for `sum()` is to sum the entire data frame.

Using `mutate` works:

```
select(iris, starts_with('Petal')) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(sum = sum(Petal.Width, Petal.Length))
```

Result:

```
Source: local data frame [150 x 3]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 150 x 3
   Petal.Length Petal.Width   sum
          <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>
 1         1.40       0.200  1.60
 2         1.40       0.200  1.60
 3         1.30       0.200  1.50
 ...
```

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that the entire data frame is passed as dot despite the `rowwise`.  To handle this use `do` which will interpret dot as meaning just the current row.  One further problem is that the dot within `do` will represent the row as a list so convert it appropriately.

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>%
  slice(1:6) %>%
  select(starts_with('Petal')) %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  do( (.) %>% as.data.frame %>% mutate(sum = sum(.)) ) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Petal.Length Petal.Width   sum
*        <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>
1         1.40       0.200  1.60
2         1.40       0.200  1.60
3         1.30       0.200  1.50
4         1.50       0.200  1.70
5         1.40       0.200  1.60
6         1.70       0.400  2.10
```

### dplyr 1.0 - added later

Since this was asked dplyr 1.0 was released and it has `cur_data()` which can be used to simplify the above eliminating the need for `do`.  `cur_data()` within a `rowwise` block refers only to the current row.

```
iris %>%
  slice(1:6) %>%
  select(starts_with('Petal')) %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(sum = sum(cur_data())) %>%
  ungroup
```

Answer (score 7):

You can skip the use of `select` if you use `c_across` to select the variables you want to sum:

```
iris %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(sum = sum(c_across(starts_with("Petal"))), .keep = "used") %>% 
  ungroup()
```

**Output**

If you want keep all the columns in your data frame then remove the `.keep` argument.

```
 Petal.Length Petal.Width   sum
          <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>
 1          1.4         0.2   1.6
 2          1.4         0.2   1.6
 3          1.3         0.2   1.5
 4          1.5         0.2   1.7
 5          1.4         0.2   1.6
 6          1.7         0.4   2.1
 7          1.4         0.3   1.7
 8          1.5         0.2   1.7
 9          1.4         0.2   1.6
10          1.5         0.1   1.6
# ... with 140 more rows
```

---

Similarly, with `max`:

```
iris %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(max = max(c_across(starts_with("Petal"))), .keep = "used") %>% 
    ungroup()
```

---

**Note**

If a row-wise aggregation function already exists it very likely much faster than using `rowwise`. For example, to get row sums, the row-wise aggregation function `rowSums` is available in base R and can be implemented like so with `across` *not* `c_across`:

```
# dplyr 1.1.0 use pick instead of across
iris %>% 
  mutate(sum = rowSums(across(starts_with("Petal"))), .keep = "used")
```

Comment: Is `c_across()` the same as `across()` ?

Comment: @Nip Good question -- no, it is not. See my [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64595719/6382434) for more detail.