# Add base R script to function?

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I have this function:

```
my_fun <- function(x) { 
  x %>%       
    separate_rows(tags, sep=',\\s*') %>%
    separate(tags, c('tags', 'Value'), sep='\\s*-\\s*', fill='right') %>%
    mutate(tags=trimws(tags)) %>% 
    count(Year, tags) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from=tags, values_from=n, values_fill=0) %>%
    adorn_totals("row") 
}
```

Is it possible to add these two lines to the function, after "adorn_totals"?
The first one orders the columns by the last row value (minus the first one), and the second sums all rows (minus the first one) and adds it as a new column

```
[c(1, order(-[nrow(), -1]) + 1)]
rowSums([, -1])
```

Comment: it's possible, but does not make much sense. You dataframe df2 is declared outside of the function. So you are creating a dependence

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. I edited it to make it make more sense hopefully?

Comment: Would it be possible to share some example data to test this function? 


For the first part of your question, I would try to use the `relocate()` dplyr function which relocates the columns. 

For the second part of your question, you might want to look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64595719/10740287

Comment: Thank you. Your link answered the second part of my question with rowwise() %>%
  mutate(sumrange = sum(c_across(2:15), na.rm = T))