# Dynamically define columns for mutate operation

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, dynamic, mutate

For a data frame, I would like to create a new column that is the sum of other columns with `dplyr`'s `mutate()`. These columns to sum over should be dynamically definable.
For example, I would like to sum two specified columns from `mtcars`:

```
library(dplyr)

columns_to_sum <- c("gear", "carb")

mtcars %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(newcol = sum(columns_to_sum))
```

but this results (expectedly) in error

> invalid 'type' (character) of argument

How should I change the last line of code so that the sum over the requested columns is taken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's relevant to this SO question: [Sum across multiple columns with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28873057/10068985). You can use tidy-selection helpers `all_of()` & `any_of()` to select variables from a character vector.

```
library(dplyr)

columns_to_sum <- c("gear", "carb")

mtcars %>%
  mutate(newcol = rowSums(pick(all_of(columns_to_sum))))
```

You can also use `rowwise` + `c_across`, but it's slower if data size is large.

```r
mtcars %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(newcol = sum(c_across(all_of(columns_to_sum)))) %>%
  ungroup()
```